Handling multiple occurrences of the same type in a variadic template parameter pack
How can I process a variadic template function in C++ to handle multiple occurrences of the same type within the template parameter pack and then pass these arguments to another variadic function?
I have the following variadic template function run that takes multiple arguments and prints them:
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void run(Args... var)
{
    (std::cout << ... << var) << std::endl;
}

I want to create another variadic template function processArgs that:

Handles multiple occurrences of the same type within the template parameter pack.
Processes these arguments and assigns them specific values.
Passes the collected arguments to the run function.

For instance, if I call processArgs<int, double, int, int, double>(), I want it to:

Create integer variables, double variables, etc., for each type in the parameter pack.
Assign specific values to these variables (e.g., incrementing values for each instance of the same type).
Pass these variables to the run function, so it behaves as if run(42, 3.14, 43, 44, 4.14) was called.

Here is the desired outcome:
int main()
{
    processArgs<int, double, int, int, double>();
    // Should result in calling: run(42, 3.14, 43, 44, 4.14), i don't care what the numbers are, it's just random
    return 0;
}

How can I implement this processArgs function to achieve the described behavior?

If you want to start from zero for each variable then I have a easy solution.  If you want different types to start at different values then it gets more complicated.  What do want?

@NathanOliver Different types to start at different values, all random

@Kitiara That might actually be not so bad to implement. Let me see what can come up with.  I might have something to start with in a bit.  Is there a range of random values you want for each type?  I assume not up to the max considering you want to increase by one each time.

@NathanOliver Yes, there is no max.

Make one new struct with your args as members and use that as template argument.

Your main aim is to pass the argument in the manner you want instead of creating random values, right? From your current wording it seems you didn't actually want "random" values but values that were set by user and you're main concern was to get a way to pass and handle the args in a specific way as you said "i don't care what the numbers are,"

@Alan Yes, that is correct. The values were just an example, perhaps the question wasn't that informative. The provided solutions are indeed solutions for the example in the question however they do not provide solution to my main concern.

@Alan I modified the description of the problem, and the example outcome. Now it is a lot more informative.

You can use class template and static data member to achieve what you want:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//wrapper 
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    static T value;
    Wrapper()
    {
        
        value++;
    } 
    
};
template<typename T> T Wrapper<T>::value{};
//specialization for random values for your types. Use random values here.
template<> int Wrapper<int>::value = 42;
template<> double Wrapper<double>::value = 3.14; 

template<typename... Args>
void run(Args... var)
{
     
    ((std::cout << var << ' '), ...) <<std::endl;
}
template<typename... T> void processArgs()
{
    run(std::forward<T>((Wrapper<T>().value)-1)...);
}
int main()
{
    processArgs<int, double, int, int, double>(); 
    
    return 0;
}

Working demo

@NathanOliver It works in working demo. I'll see what the standard says and maybe ask a new question.

@NathanOliver I'll create a new question. Meanwhile, I'll edit this answer to specialize the whole class.

Looks like GCC and MSVC both error, clang compiles.

@NathanOliver The error only comes when we use inline with the static data member. If we use the old out of class definition way of doing things then gcc and msvc also starts accepting the program. Demo

@user12002570 Thank you for your solution to my previous question. I realized my main goal was not clearly stated. Instead of creating random values, my aim is to pass specific values to the variadic template function but it went the wrong way. For example, I want to call processArgs("text", 4.6, 'c', 4, "more text", 7.8, 'd') and have it pass these exact values to the run function. I've updated my question to reflect this intent more clearly.

@Kitiara As I was expecting, that is why I didn't use random etc in my answer. Note that your new follow up question is entirely different from the original question. Feel free to create a new separate question. Editing your old question to contain the new question is not recommended as it will invalidate the already 2 posted questions.

@user12002570 Sure, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78808660/implementing-a-variadic-template-function-to-call-stored-class-member-functions

@Kitiara I've added an answer there that uses std::tuple instead of std::unordered_map.

New answer based on question update:
You basically will have the same template form for processArgs as you do run, you just need to call run with the argument pack.  That looks like
template<typename... Args> 
void processArgs(Args... args) 
{
    run(args...);
}

If you want to perfectly forward everything through, which doesn't seem like you do since you have the string literals decay to pointers, then you would have
template<typename... Args> 
void processArgs(Args&&... args) 
{
    run(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


Old Answer:
Here is one way to get something like what you want.
First we start with the helper functions
template<std::integral T>
T random_start()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dis(1,1000); // use whatever range you want
    return dis(gen);
}

template<std::floating_point T>
T random_start()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dis(1.0, 2.0);
    return dis(gen);
}

That gets a random integer or floating point number.  Then we can leverage that into a statefull function template of the form
template<typename T>
T& get_val()
{
    static T val = random_start<T>();
    return val;
}

This function creates a static T for each T that is in the Args of processArgs.  Speaking of, lets introduce processArgs:
template<typename... Args>
void processArgs()
{
    std::tuple<Args...> params{(get_val<Args>()++)...};
    std::apply([](auto... args) { run(args...); }, params);
}

It might seem strange that I introduced a tuple and then have to use apply with a helper lambda to call run but the "simple" solution of
template<typename... Args>
void processArgs()
{
    run(get_val<Args>()++...);
}

has a flaw in that the order of evaluation of function arguments in not specified and typically be left to right on Windows and right to left on *Nix.  This means on some systems the values will "decrease" in print order when the function is called. You can see that in this live example.
So putting this all together we get:
template<typename... Args>
void run(Args... var)
{
    ((std::cout << var << std::endl), ...);
}

template<std::integral T>
T random_start()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dis(1,1000); // use whatever range you want
    return dis(gen);
}

template<std::floating_point T>
T random_start()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dis(1.0, 2.0);
    return dis(gen);
}

template<typename T>
T& get_val()
{
    static T val = random_start<T>();
    return val;
}

template<typename... Args>
void processArgs()
{
    //run(get_val<Args>()++...);
    std::tuple<Args...> params{(get_val<Args>()++)...};
    std::apply([](auto... args) { run(args...); }, params);
}

int main()
{
    processArgs<int, double, int, int, double>();
}

and in this live example it gives the output of
506
1.29876
507
508
2.29876


Thank you for your solution to my previous question. I realized my main goal was not clearly stated. Instead of creating random values, my aim is to pass specific values to the variadic template function but it went the wrong way. For example, I want to call processArgs("text", 4.6, 'c', 4, "more text", 7.8, 'd') and have it pass these exact values to the run function. I've updated my question to reflect this intent more clearly.

@Kitiara I've added an update that should do what you asked for in your update.

Yes that works for the (std::cout << ... << var) << std::endl; case but its not working if we are holding a std::function of vectors where each function require different parameters.

@Kitiara Can you give an example?

@Kitiara Note that you should not edit your question such that it changes the whole intent of the question when there are already 2 answers posted. Feel free to ask a new separate question for your different intent question. As a general rule, if the new follow up question is sufficiently different from the original question, then one should ask a new question so that already posted answers don't get invaidated.
