Implementing a variadic template function to call stored class member functions by identifier?
How can I store a member function and implement a variadic template function to call stored functions with specific arguments?
Let's assume I have stored member functions of some classes into a container which is indexed by an identifier.
I want to create a variadic template function processArgs that:

Takes an identifier and a set of arguments.
Finds the corresponding function in the map using the identifier.
Calls the function with the provided arguments.
The stored function may be a const

Here is the outline of the problem:
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class MyClass {
public:
    void someFunc(const char* str, int a, double b) {
        std::cout << str << " " << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }

    float magnitude(double x, double y, double z) {
        return sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
    }

    std::string toStr(float x) {
        return std::to_string(x);
    }
};

using fnId = int;

std::unordered_map<fnId, Ret (Classes::*)(Args...)> functions; // This is going to be filled with functions

template<typename... Args>
void processArgs(int fnId, Args... args)
{
    // This function will retrieve a function by fnId, and forward args in specific order/type to that specific function, for that specific object
    // so it will be like obj->someFunc(args...);
}

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    
    // Assuming the container is filled with functions
    functions[0] = &MyClass::someFunc;
    functions[1] = &MyClass::magnitude;
    functions[2] = &MyClass::toStr;
    
    // This is how i execute 
    processArgs(0, "text", 30, 3.34);
    processArgs(1, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0);
    processArgs(2, 3.14159);
    
    return 0;
}

Bonus: How can I make processArgs to return the result of the executed function if that particular executed function has a return type? For example processArgs(1, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0) should return the calculated value.

What you are attempting is not possible in C++. The method pointers in the map must have the same signature. You can't use a parameter pack outside of a template, and you can't store a template in a container. What you could do is have the methods take an array of variant, and then you can convert your processArgs parameters to such an array

@RemyLebeau Of course we can't store a template in a container, it's a demonstration of the problem. I didn't want to redirect somebody by putting there a void* or something else.

@Kitiara You can use std::tuple instead of unorered_map as shown in this demo and my answer below.

Imagine what should happen for mismathcing id/args, i.e processArgs(0, 3.14159);?

@Jarod42 That kind of behaviour must be detectable, then you throw an error.

With full runtime argument, return type cannot be deduced.


How can I make processArgs to return the result of the executed function if that particular executed function has a return type?

You can use std::tuple to achieve what you want as shown below. Note the use of std::make_tuple and auto to make code more readable. Also with c++17, we can use std::invoke.
//create std::tuple
auto functions = std::make_tuple( &MyClass::someFunc, &MyClass::magnitude, &MyClass::toStr); 

template<int fnId, typename... Args>
auto processArgs( const Args&... args)
{
    using std::get;
    MyClass obj;
    //with C++17 we use std::invoke 
    return std::invoke(get<fnId>(functions), obj, args...);
}

int main()
{
    // This is how i execute 
    processArgs<0>( "text", 30, 3.34);
    processArgs<1>( 2.0, 4.0, 6.0);
    processArgs<2>( 3.14159);
}

Working demo
Note that the fnId is now a template parameter so that it can be used as template argument to std::get.

The fnId becomes the tuple element id in this case and there is no function container, which is against the whole idea. Thanks for trying though

@Kitiara The problem with using containers like unordered_map is that you can't store different types(in this case pointer to member function). I was highlighting that using container is not the optimal/recommended solution here in the first plac. I can probably make this work by using void* etc but that would be the best solution. Btw are you allowed to use C++20?

@Kitiara Are you allowed to use void* and C++23?

@Kitiara This looks like an XY problem. Why not use tuple when it achieves the same behavior.

@user12002570 Yes C++20, C++23 and void* is fine.

@Alan Because there is no collection of functions. It is what makes the problem harder anyway
